# Log4j2 - Program doesn't log when replacing Log4j2 imports by slf4j ones

Tags: log4j2, slf4j

My programs stops log in files just by replacing:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

with

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

I'm using : **OracleJdk8**, **log4j-core-2.17.1** and **slf4j-sample-2.0.0-alpha6**

Please find bellow my **log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">C:/path/to/logfile</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="functional-log" fileName="${log-path}/functional.log" filePattern="${log-path}/functional-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="INFO" maxLevel="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="technical-1-log" fileName="${log-path}/technical.log" filePattern="${log-path}/technical-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="DEBUG" maxLevel="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="technical-2-log" fileName="${log-path}/technical.log" filePattern="${log-path}/technical-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="WARN" maxLevel="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/error.log" filePattern="${log-path}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.err">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="x.y.z" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="functional-log" level="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="technical-1-log" level="TRACE" />
            <appender-ref ref="technical-2-log" level="WARN" />
            <appender-ref ref="error-log" level="ERROR" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console-log" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

By this configuration, I'd like to log :

- "**ERROR**" and "**FATAL**" in error.err file.
- "**TRACE**", "**DEBUG**" and "**WARN**" in technical.log file.
- "**INFO**" in functional.log file.

Could you please indicate me the right way to use slf4j import to still logging in RollingFile?

Knowing that `org.slf4j.Logger.fatal()` method doesn't exist :(

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: `slf4j-sample-2.0.0-alpha6`: this is an alpha version and is not yet supported by Log4j 2.x (cf. [LOG4J2-3370](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3370)). BTW: the Log4j 2.x API offers the same functionality as SLF4J and is actively maintained.

Comment: Thank you Piotr for your answer.
I've also tried with `slf4j-sample-1.7.36` but it doesn't work too.
Actually I prefer work with slf4j imports instead of log4j2 ones because maybe will migrate to logback implementation in the futur.